# How to get the selected row ID and use it for a delete query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have data in DataGridView, and I want to delete a row from it by selection. I have a button DELETE on the form which hold the delete query

`var note = (from n in dataCont.Past_Notes
                        where n.ID == ?
                        select n).First();`

It works perfectly if I specify an ID manually in the code.(where the question mark is)

But I don't wanna do it like this. How to get the index of the selected row, and then delete that row?

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Past_Sticky_NotesDataContext dataCont = new Past_Sticky_NotesDataContext();

     var note = (from n in dataCont.Past_Notes
                 where n.ID == ?
                 select n).First();

     dataCont.Past_Notes.DeleteOnSubmit(note);
     dataCont.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

I *have* to use LINQ queries.

Comment: You should have a SelectedRow property in your DataGrid. Something like this: DataGrid.Rows.SelectedRow, and then you can get your Id - selectedRow[0].

Answer (score 0):

You need to Set `DataGridView.MultiSelect=false` and `DataGridView.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect.`
then `your_dataGridView_name.SelectedRows[0]` - this will return selected row. Then you get value of id cell in your row `selectedRow.Cells[your_id_index]`. And use it in LINQ query

**Edit**

Or you can use another property to get your selectedRow index `datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex`

Comment: Ok, I did this : 

`private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
               int index = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        }`

Now how do I include it in the query?

Comment: Like this from n in ...where n.id == dataGrid.selectedRows[0].cells[0].value. But create local variable for id

Comment: I tried doing this

`n.ID == dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value`

but it gives an error.

Is it because I dont create that extra variable for id ? 
I'm a rookie at this, can you show me how to declare it ?

Comment: Maybe I have some missmatch in my example (if this is winforms -I have use it long time ago), but you can try to debug it, and set a breakpoint in your handler. Than in watch window try to explore datagridview properties. Maybe you have not selected rows or smt else. Also please add the exception message to your question

Comment: I'm sorry  Andriy Khrystyanovich, I'm a bit confused :/

Let me show you what I have now:

    `private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
               int index = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        }`

And on the button click event: 

`int Row_ID = (int)dataGridView1["ColumnName", index].Value;
            var note = (from n in dataCont.Past_Notes
                        where n.ID == Row_ID
                        select n).First();`

How to get _index_ to be recognized in this context?What to write under _Column name_?